# Does running a node HTTPS server with a self-signed certificate defeat the purpose of using HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, server, self-signed

I'm a bit confused here. I want to run a node server which will be queried from some clients. I'm trying to use HTTPS, which I am not familiar with.

After reading some guides and the node docs, I created a key and self signed certificate with openssl, and created a node HTTPS server. So far so good.

The problem is, when trying to query it (I'm doing it from a node script as a test), I get an `error: self signed certificate`. Fixing this seems to involve using a `rejectUnauthorized: false` option when sending the request.

So my question: Does this defeat the purpose of using HTTPS, or is the communication still encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a self-signed cert, your traffic is *encrypted*, but not *authenticated* (leaving you open to man-in-the-middle attacks).

You can get free certificates from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/); why not use that?

Comment: Bceause I didn't know about it. This is all new territory for me. I'll look into it, thanks for the info

Comment: You'll probably be interested in [letsencrypt-express](https://github.com/Daplie/letsencrypt-express), which handles everything automatically for a node server.

Comment: Do I understand this right: this will automatically request a letsencrypt certificate when i access the server over http, and us/serve that certificate over https?

Comment: Very cool. Would this work on a host that says I only have "shared ssl"? Looking at OpenShift free plan...

Comment: Probably not.  The express plugin requires you to do SSL termination on your server.  If free is your largest concern, try heroku, which gives you a free web server with SSL support.